# Questionnaire Radio button unchecks after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm quite new with vue and did a questionnaire with radio buttons and a backwards navigations which remember the preview answer and sets it to checked. But I'm facing an obscure issue.

The first version was with a simple set of radio buttons and a sentAnswer button which emit the answer.

A Second iteration was without and a sentAnswer button. The radio button itself had a eventhandler attached and emits the answer.

Both version worked pretty well.

Now i want to have both a sentAnswer Button and a delayed eventhandler for the radio buttons which emits the answer after a certain time. The code is working fine except of on bug. When i click a radio button it is unchecked immediately afterwards. When i removed the eventhandler attached to the radio button the radio button work as expected.

```
Vue.component('question', {
  template: `
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in" 
  v-on:after-leave="afterLeave">
  <div :key="question.id"> 

    <div class="Questionnaire-answers">
    <strong>Question {{ questionNumber }}:</strong><br/>
    <h2>{{ question.text }} </h2> 
      <div v-for="(choice,index) in question.choices" >
      <input type="radio" :id="'answer'+index" :name="question.id" :value="choice.value"  :data-next="choice.nextStage" @click="handleAnswer" :checked="question.lastAnswer == choice.value" ><label :for="'answer'+index">{{choice.answer}}</label><br/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" >
    <div v-show="errorsForm">
      <p>Please select an answer!</p>
    </div>
    </transition>
    <div class="border">
      <button v-if="question.stage !== '1'" @click="returnAnswer" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-primary-inverted-md">Back</button>
      <!--button @click="submitAnswer" class="btn btn-danger">Answer</button-->
    </div>
    <div v-show="answerHasGiven" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
`,
  data() {


    return {
      answerHasGiven : false,
      errorsForm: false,
      answer: null
    }
  },
  props: ['question', 'question-number'],
  methods: {
    submitAnswer: function () {
      const val = $('input:checked').val();
      if (val !== undefined) {
        this.errorsForm = false;
        this.$emit('answer', {answer: val});
      } else {
        this.errorsForm = true;
      }



    },

    handleAnswer: function () {

      this.answerHasGiven = true;
      const self = this;
      const val = $(event.target).val();
      $(event.target).prop('checked',true)
      setTimeout(function () {
        this.answerHasGiven = false;
        self.$emit('answer', {answer: val});

      }, 4000);
    },

    returnAnswer: function () {
      this.$emit('answer', {answer: "backwards"});
      this.answer = null;
    },

    afterLeave: function (el) {
      this.answerHasGiven = false;
      //$('.Questionnaire-answers input:checked').prop('checked',false);
    }
  }
})
;
```

The afterLeave function doesn't seem to be the problem because it never called at the time the radio button is checked. I Tryed this with the debugger.

When the component is called it gets a questionobject with the question, answer and values. If this question was already answered lastanswer presets the radio button.

I'm quite new to vue, so I'm shure this maybe not the perfect approach, but any advice is welcome.

Comment: inside setTimeout, make it `self.answerHasGiven = false;` that must be breaking your code.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that, but is doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found my error.

it is in this line:

```
<input type="radio" :id="'answer'+index" :name="question.id" :value="choice.value"  :data-next="choice.nextStage" @click="handleAnswer" :checked="question.lastAnswer == choice.value" ><label :for="'answer'+index">{{choice.answer}}</label><br/>
```

The radio button deselects because of this condition:

```
:checked="question.lastAnswer == choice.value"
```

Vue is setting the current active state of the radio button according to this. If the lastaAnswer is unset which it is for every new question, this condition evalutes to false and the radio button is unchecked.

In other words vue is setting the radiobuttons checked status according to the current value of this variables. It simply overrides everything...

The simple soulution of this, is to give lastAnswer the current value of the last clicked element.

```
    handleAnswer: function () {

  if (!this.answerHasGiven) {
    const self = this;
    const val = $(event.target).val();
    this.question.lastAnswer = val;
    $(event.target).prop('checked', true);
    this.answerHasGiven = true;
    setTimeout(function () {

      self.$emit('answer', {answer: val});

    }, 1000);
  }
},
```

Thanks for time.